# tensorflow probability per class

Tags: tensorflow, probability

I want to get probability per class, for my output, in tensorflow.
Using softmax yields the following.

```
A : 0.7
B : 0.2
C : 0.1
```

But, what I want is

```
A probability : 0.8
B probability : 0.6
C probability : 0.7
```

Comment: The numbers you say you want do not add up to 1.0 so they are not probabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `softmax`, use [`tf.nn.sigmoid`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sigmoid) as

```
tf.nn.sigmoid(<output-tensor>)
```